# Cannot configure enzyme adapter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I am attempting to configure the enzyme adapter for testing. The code I have is this, very simple:

```
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

enzyme.configure({adapter : new Adapter()});
```

I get an error as follows:

```
import Adapter
Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.ts(2351)
setupTests.ts(2, 1): Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import require here instead.
```

Could this be a versioning issue? I am following a react-typescript guide from 2 years ago.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Minor mistake.

Changed:

```
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
```

To:

```
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
```